# Setting up cx_Oracle and Oracle 11g for Django, name vs host? Where to put Instant Client?

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/rpost/django-with-an-oracle-legacy-db-45gl) to connect django with a legacy oracle database a little confused what to put in the Name. In addition, I'm a little confused how to install the Instant Client so that my django/python application will be able to see the instant client.

I'm on Windows 10, django 3.0.1, python 3.8

1.) First of all, when I connect to the database with the enterprise manager, I see this (edited):
[image]

So when I fill in my django, this is what I put(edited):

[image]

**in the Name, am I suppose to put ServerName (following the enterprise manager image) or do I put servername/schema that I'm trying to connect to?**

2.) I contacted the admin, and the Oracle database is 11g, and also in Visual Studio, I connected to the database and checked the version, it is

[image]

So I download the [instant client for 11.2.0.4.0 (32 bit)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html)

I use 32bit because I think my python is 32 bit.

[image]

Unzipped it into C:\instantclient_11_2
Added C:\instantclient_11_2 to my System Environment Variables, in the PATH

And tried to run the following

[image]

And I receive the error:

[image]

[But according to the documentation here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#initialization), I need to set it to lib_dir, but **I'm not sure where the lib_dir variable is?** is this an environment variable? Or something in my application? Settings.py?

Comment: are you using cx_Oracle 8.0 ?

Comment: the DIPI-1072 means that either the instant client is 32 and your Python probably is 64

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I have cx_Oracle 8.0 DO I need a lower version?
Also i tried both 32 and 64 bit and restarted PC both times when adding it to the environment variables, and it still gives me the same error. So I'm not sure if I'm installing the instant client correctly.

Comment: I would use a newer version. You can connect from a 18c or 19c client to a 11g database.

Comment: Ok I just tried 19.6 32 bit, and it was an improvement, I got a different error this time, but I think it's closer to connecting than the previous.

Comment: if you want to post an answer i can accept it

Comment: @ansarc, answer posted. really appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would use an Oracle client 18c or 19c . Both can connect to a 11g database without any issue.

Using 11g version with cx_Oracle 8.0 might lead to issues.